# How to rank ordinal data?

Tags: dataset, likert, ranking

I have 33 indicators and I asked 16 experts to indicate the significance of each indicators using 5 points Likert questionnaire. So basically for each indicator I have 16 scores (each score varies from 1-5). I want to rank these indicators. But how? Any idea? I believe I need a non-parametric method. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to questions like this, there's no "right" answer. I've been there before.

The easiest way is to just take average scores, weighting 1st as 5 points, 2nd as 4 points, etc.

An overkill way (that I've used before) is to do some variable clustering or unsupervised learning techniques (eg: PCA) to see which experts agreed most with each other. Following the logic of "consensus of the experts is probably correct", you can restrict your ranking to only those who agree most with each-other.

Without more context it's hard to make a recommendation. How much time do you have? What is the data about? Can you get a bigger sample size than 16? etc.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. The survey was done last year and I am trying to publish a paper out of it. Data is about the assessment of a technical term in construction industry. I categorized the 33 indicators into 4 categories then.Each of these indicators are some words, kind of recommendations. At that time(last year) I used the mean rank in the process of Friedman test to rank these indicators. However, I feel like I may be not correct.  
Does a bigger sample size change anything? If so how big do I need?

Thanks

Comment: A bigger sample size will definitely help a reader to believe you. I wouldn't put too much stock in a paper that says "we surveyed 16 people".

Comment: That is reasonable. Do you think 32 will be enough? How about 50? What is the meaning of "enough" for me? How can I come up with this number?

Comment: More would of course be nicer. Maybe you can look into similar papers (that got published using only survey data) to see how big their samples were?